# How can I scan portions of a huge Scala Array[Byte] for individual Chars?

Tags: scala

I have a very large Array[Byte] that I would like to scan for particular characters.  Let's assume the encoding is UTF-8.  I basically want to look for specific Chars, and convert slices of the array to (sub)strings to parse individual JSON objects.  I'd rather not produce a ginormous String from the Array[Byte].  I expect to find very many small JSON objects in the array.  Not all the objects will have the same key/value pairs.  I'll only be interested in some of the objects that have key/values of interest.  I know how to convert Array[Byte] to String, I just don't know how to do it incrementally or piecemeal.

Comment: If you have to scan the entire thing why wouldn't you want to turn it into a giant string? You're going to wind up doing that anyway.

Comment: @wheaties It's possible I might be able to have the Array[Byte] be filled lazily, that's the only reason.

Comment: Your code will likely be a lot simpler if you do convert it to a string because otherwise you couldn't use regex or even simple text searching that's built into `String` and also if you're dealing with UTF-8 then one character might be spread across several bytes.

Comment: `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: Thank you all.  Your points are spot on and I do have an implementation that works just using Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [CharsetDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).

```
import java.nio.{ByteBuffer, CharBuffer}
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

val bytes: Array[Byte] = ...

val charset = StandardCharserts.UTF_8
val decoder = charset.newDecoder

// decode 1KB
val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 0, 1024)
val charBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate((int)(charset.averageCharsPerByte * 1024 + 1))
decoder.decode(byteBuffer, charBuffer, false)

// the first byteBuffer.position() bytes have been decoded
// as charBuffer.position() characters, which can be converted to
// a String via charBuffer.toString()
```

There are error conditions and such, but anyway, that should give you a start for incrementally decoding.

Note that this is a general algorithm that works with any encoding that Java recognizes. If you assume a particular encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16), you can create less general code.

---

FYI, since you mentioned streaming the comments, using very similar code, I [created](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/cde65d987b6cf3c307dfab8269b87a65c5e84575/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/CharEncoding.scala) an `Enumeratee[[Array[Byte], Array[Char]]` for the Play framework that incrementally converts a non-blocking byte stream into a non-blocking char stream.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you @PaulDraper, that's exactly what I was looking for.